# Не работает client.get_user(id) в discord.py

Tags: python

При запуске и вводе корректных данных выводит в консоль "none", а затем переменная `guilf`, так и `user`. Код:

```
import discord
import sys

client = discord.Client()

from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from code import Ui_Dialog

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
ui = Ui_Dialog()
ui.setupUi(Dialog)
Dialog.show()

#functions
async def podgt():
    txt_msg = ui.lineEdit.text()
    txt_id = ui.lineEdit_1.text()
    print(txt_msg)
    print(txt_id)
    guild = client.get_guild("592627430137528320")
    user = client.get_user(int(txt_id))
    print(user)
ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(podgt)

sys.exit(app.exec_())
client.run("токен")
```

Comment: `qt` не сможет работать с `async`, уберите это у функции. Накидал тестовый пример с кнопкой и `async` функцией и при клике получил ошибку в трассу: `RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'podgt' was never awaited`

Comment: у меня не установлены модули, с которыми вы работаете. Я не понимаю, что у вас делает `client.run("токен")` , это написано после `sys.exit(app.exec_())` и никогда не будет выполнено. Также посмотрите пост https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1114768/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8B-pyqt может будет чем-то полезен.